# Добавление элемента в двухсвязный список

Tags: c++, список

Нужна функция, которая просто добавляет элемент в начало. Я вот кое что написал, но там еще нужно, что то делать с указателем на предыдущий элемент, так как у меня двусвязный список, помогите переделать.

```
void add(INFO d, BOOK *&head)
{
    BOOK *tmp = new BOOK;
    tmp->data = d;
    tmp->next = head;
    head=tmp;
}
```

Comment: @Алексей Гауба, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

```
BOOK *add(INFO d, BOOK *head)  // head указатель на первый элемент списка
{      // для создания нового списка вызвать list = add(d,NULL);
       // для добавления в существующий      list = add(d,list);
   BOOK *tmp = new BOOK;
   tmp->data = d;
   tmp->next = head;
   tmp->previous = NULL;
   if (head!=NULL)             // список уже существует
      head->previous = tmp; 
   return tmp;
 }
```

Comment: Да, так лучше. Только все равно вызывает вопрос, что будет если new обломается. :-)

Comment: Ну, конечно упадет. В реальной программе это надо обрабатывать в соответствии со смыслом всей задачи. Может записать сообщение в log и завершить процесс, а может просто (разумеется не падая) вернуть NULL и т.д.

Comment: @Алёна Непомнящая: Оу. Вы бы почитали книжку по C++, а? В C++ `-` и `>` вместе понимается как один оператор `->` (стрелка), он означает "доступ к полю по указателю на структуру".

Answer (score 0):

Это моя реализация функции для деки, делал довольно таки давно. Возможно что то придется додумать.

```
deck addhead(deck d, int data){ //добавление в голову
    elem *t=(elem*)malloc(sizeof(elem)); //Выделение памяти под новый элемент
    t->data=data; //Запись данных в новый элемент
    t->next=d.head; //Указание следующего элемента - нынешнюю голову
    t->prev=NULL; //Установка указателя на предыдущий элемент в NULL
    if(!isempty(d)){ //Если дека не пуста
        d.head->prev=t; //Указание у нынешней головы предыдущего элемента - нового элемента
    }
    d.head=t; //запись в указатель головы указателя на новый элемент
    return d; //Возвращение деки
}
```